# Determining whether a TreeMap is equal to a Map in java

Tags: java, dictionary, tree, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I am coding an implementation of Prim's algorithm for deriving a Minimum Spanning Tree. My Graph is a `Map<String, ArrayList>` in which they keys correspond to the state name and the values are the edges which hold pointers to both links.

Prim's Algorithm says I should start with a Tree only containing the starting node then loop until my tree is equivalent to my graph. How can I determine equivalence of a `TreeMap<String, ArrayList>` and `Map<String, ArrayList>`?

Comment: What about instanceof?

Comment: How do you define "equivalence"?  Once you understand that, it should be simple to iterate over both data structures and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

If by equivalence you mean key, value pairs in both maps are exactly same then you can simply use Map.equals() method which checks if entry set is same for both maps.